# How to create enterprise specific private channel in YouTube?

Tags: javascript, youtube, ionic-framework, youtube-api

I am developing an ionic application and it has feature of playing YouTube videos.

Query 1:

Service gives the you tube URL and the application loads and shows it on screen.
Now this YouTube video URL is open and anybody with URL can view.

Is there any configuration to avoid that ? YouTube do have 3 [public,unlisted,private] configuration but that wont suite since this is Enterprise product.

Query 2:

Also, we are planning for offline viewing.

Is downloading officially allowed.If yes, do we need to purchase any license ?

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: I think it's best that you read this stack post. [Link](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/is-downloading-youtube-videos-legal)

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the below links:

```
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/NyO7mORC2mo

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwibyZKL4ojNAhUHnZQKHYNiA5QQtwIIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D9qZAfcZx6U0&usg=AFQjCNFQSRUmQca2S-dm3ouvosSJF36LEQ&sig2=oo0zmHL1tR66ehNTZz2_6Q&bvm=bv.123325700,d.bGs
```

Hope these would be helpful.